# when I run my app on device having api greater then 19 it gives me error

Tags: android, runtimeexception, inflate-exception, invocationtargetexception

I am testing my app on  diffrent api level. It works fine on `minsdk` i.e `API 19` but when i run my app on device having `API > 19` it give me runtime exception.

```
minSdk =19

TargetSdk =27
```

If my code is having any error or bug than it should not be run on any device. But it is running properly on device having `API 19` but not on the device having `API > 19`.

**Complete stack trace**

```
Process: com.example.lenovo.jdstudio, PID: 5151
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView
                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView
                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:742)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
                      at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:236)
                      at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:198)
                      at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:392)
                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:296)
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.SetupActivity.startSetupAccount(SetupActivity.java:95)
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.SetupActivity.access$000(SetupActivity.java:31)
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.SetupActivity$1.onClick(SetupActivity.java:68)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22295)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_material with resource ID #0x108065d
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d0006: .xml extension required
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:963)
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:784)
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:863)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1016)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:533)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(GradientDrawable.java:1268)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.applyTheme(GradientDrawable.java:1206)
                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:594)
                      at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:308)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:872)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
                      at android.view.View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(View.java:5101)
                      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4642)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
                      at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:180)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:176)
                      at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:172)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:742)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
                      at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:236)
                      at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:198)
                      at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:392)
                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:296)
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.SetupActivity.startSetupAccount(SetupActivity.java:95)
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.SetupActivity.access$000(SetupActivity.java:31)
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.SetupActivity$1.onClick(SetupActivity.java:68)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22295)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

**"activity_main.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/navigation_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_container">


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">
        <include
            layout="@layout/navigation_header" />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**image_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/placeholder4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Image Title Goes Here"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_resol"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="Image Resol Goes here" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.HomeFragment">


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_list">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your xml please

Comment: post the your xml file the solution live there

Comment: post your java and xml code please

Comment: `mipmap` folder should be used only for storing launcher icons, try moving your resources to `drawable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d0006:
```

[**`Resources$NotFoundException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException.html)

This exception is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested resource can not be found.

> Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.png

You should delete **`mipmap-xxhdpi-v4`** folder. It should be **`mipmap-xxhdpi`**

Comment: i dont find any folder with this name

Comment: @Aakash Your some images are absent according to logcat. You should add them in right folders.

Comment: I have checked all the images are present in all the mipmap folder

Comment: @Aakash `all the images` means ? mipmap for app icons other images replace to Drawble folders

Comment: can you please come on team viewer and hlep me in this? please

Comment: Ohk NP ty for this much help

Answer (score 1):

On First Look on your Logcat , the error is occured due to Resource Not Found.

1) android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_material - NOT FOUND

2) res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp.png - NOT FOUND

Thats why the error - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line